# How to use query builder or raw SQL within a Laravel Eloquent relationship

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm using Laravel's Eloquent ORM, but want to define a complex relationship and was wondering if it were possible to use the query builder or raw SQL when defining a relationship.

This is the schema:

Table: objects; Model: Object

Table: users; Model: User

Table: objects_users; Relationship: ManyToMany - An object can be owned by many users, a user can own many objects.

Using a traditional relationship would work fine for normal records, ones that are entered individually into the pivot table. However, I also want to return additional results depending on additional criteria; i.e. allow all objects to belong to a user if they have a debugger flag set. Essentially, I want to mimic this query:

```
SELECT objects.*
FROM objects
LEFT JOIN objects_users ON objects.id = objects_users.object_id
INNER JOIN users ON
    objects_users.user_id = users.id
    OR users.debugger = 1
```

Alternatively, if this can't be done, is it possible to return eloquent models from a query builder query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
    $objects = DB::select('select objects.* from objects 
    LEFT JOIN objects_users ON objects.id = objects_users.object_id
    INNER JOIN users ON
    objects_users.user_id = users.id
    OR users.debugger = 1');`
```

After that you can "convert" the raw result-Objects to your specified Model like that:

```
$objArray = array();
$objArray = YourObjectModel::hydrate($objects);
```

Hope this will help you! 
Have a nice christmas anyway ;)

Comment: Excellent, I like it. Very simple. Not 100% what I was after, but I think it's a much cleaner solution than the route I was originally going down! Thanks a lot for your help.